# What is the difference between Nightwatch and Capybara?

Tags: testing, vue.js, capybara, integration, nightwatch.js

I'm using a Vue front-end with a Rails back-end and I'm looking at options for unit testing and integration tests. I'm considering Jest for unit tests, but I'm a little confused on the options for integration tests. What is the difference between Nightwatch and Capybara? Is it just that Nightwatch runs in Node and Capybara runs in Ruby?